# No Users with granted login under subscribers in Licence Management App

Tags: managed-package, isv, licenses, partner

We have users that have granted us login access. However, we do not see their names under their subscribed org in LMA. What could be causing this? Package, package version, subscribers look correct and updated

Comment: Most likely cause, they did not grant access to you. Maybe they picked "Salesforce Support" or created a user for you and misunderstood what you were asking. Have them send you a screenshot of the page where they granted access. If it does indeed show access has been granted, you will need to open a case with SF. There are many moving parts with the LMA.....

Comment: Was this in the License tab or the Subscriber tab?

Comment: under the subscriber page from the subscribers tab